# Read Excel with PHPExcel and insert array with MeekroDB

Tags: php, mysqli, phpexcel, meekro

I'm getting a list of columns from an Excel with PHPExcel, so far everything is fine, I can get the array and see the data on screen, even the columns that interest me and omitting the first rows, the problem is that I can not insert these array results in a database, I can not even insert the first record in the array. Can you help me? Thank you!

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
require_once 'Excel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('prices.xlsx');

$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

foreach($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();

    for($row=8; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
    {
        $column1 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue();
        $column2 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getValue();
        $column3 = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, $row)->getValue();

        $finaldata[] = array(
            'Key'           =>      trim($column1),
            'Price'         =>      trim($column2),
            'currency'      =>      trim($column3),
        );
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($finaldata);
die();
?>
```

I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Key] => 100001
            [Price] => 40.83
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Key] => 100002
            [Price] => 624.94
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Key] => 100003
            [Price] => 69.74
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Key] => 100004
            [Price] => 150.62
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Key] => 100005
            [Price] => 223.15
            [currency] => USD
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Key] => 100006
            [Price] => 92.94
            [currency] => USD
        )
)
```

Now I'm trying to insert all the records in my database with the following code:

```
<?php
    DB::insert('prices', array(
        'Key' => $column1,
        'Price' => $column2,
        'currency' => $column3
    ));
?>
```

I hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance for your time!